# how to formulate this statement if A8 (value) is found in a range H$8:AL$57 then C8 otherwise zero (o)

Tags: excel

How to formulate to find a value in certain range to select specific cell in return. Or simply please formulate this statement  if A8 (value) is found in a range H$8:AL$57 then C8 otherwise zero (o) .

Comment: this formula will be placed in D8

Answer (score 0):

Try using `COUNTIF` in an IF function, e.g. in cell D8 use this formula

`=IF(COUNTIF(H$8:AL$57,A8)>0,C8,0)`

Comment: soooooooooooooooooooooo nice of you, blessings Barry Houdini!!!! u solved my concern :)